# Google Maps V3 API setMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say I have the following objects:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...)
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(...);
```

I can add `marker` to `map` with:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

If the marker already exists on the map, and I call `marker.setMap(map)` again, does the API actually redraw the marker? Or does it know the marker already exists on the map, so it doesn't take any further actions?

I am listening for events and need to either add or remove markers from the map when those events occur. I'm wondering if I can simply keep calling `setMap(map)` even if the marker already exists without performance suffering significantly, or do I need to be smarter and not call `setMap` in the first place if the marker is already on the map.

If you don't know the answer, do you have any idea how I could figure this out?

Comment: The end of my question specifically asks for advice on how to test it because I do not know how. Perhaps you were too lazy to read the entire question?

Comment: I've had memory leaks and performance problems before @flyingL123, I used chrome developer tools to take heap snapshots between refreshes, and see has the number of marker objects increased with each refresh.  This really helped and found I need to set markers to null, and detach their events etc. to get rid of them from memory.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> If the marker already exists on the map, and I call marker.setMap(map)
>   again, does the API actually redraw the marker? Or does it know the
>   marker already exists on the map, so it doesn't take any further
>   actions?

The setMap function work on the visibility of the marker... assing to the marker in which map object this marker must be place/visibile.. 
If you set marker.setMap(null) you don't destroy the marker simply is not more showed in the "map".

when you manage event on marker you can use setMap(null) for make the marker invisible.. if you have previuosly stored the marker object in some var..eg

```
 var store_marker = marker;
```

you can simply turn it on again doing

```
  store_marke.setMap(map);
```

You can use array for manage collection of markers